# Tricky php string matching

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[2005]
one 
two
three
[2004]
six
```

What would be the smoothest was to get an array from it that would look like this:

```
array(
    ['2005'] => "one \n two \n three",
    ['2005'] => "six",
)
```

... or maybe even get the inner array sliced into lines array...

I tried doing it with preg_split, which worked but didn't give associative array keys so I didn't have the year numbers as keys.

Is there any cool way of doing this without iterating through all the lines ?

Comment: Note that your output has a typo - should be '2004' => "six"

Comment: Whether you use e.g. `while(fread)` or a native function, you still have to read through the string. I would regex each line in a loop to search for the [year] pattern rather than regex the entire string at once. Break the problem into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/(\[[0-9]{4}\])([^\[]*)/` will give you the date and whatever is after until the next one.

Use the groups to create your array: With `preg_match_all()` you get a $matches array where $matches[1] is the date and $matches[2] is the data following it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sylverdrag's regex as a guide:

```
<?php
$test = "[2005]
one
two
three
[2004]
six";

$r = "/(\[[0-9]{4}\])([^\[]*)/";
preg_match_all($r, $test, $m);
$output = array();
foreach ($m[1] as $key => $name)
{
    $name = str_replace(array('[',']'), array('',''), $name);
    $output[ $name ] = $m[2][$key];
}

print_r($output);
?>
```

Output (PHP 5.2.12):

```
Array
(
    [2005] =>
one
two
three

    [2004] =>
six
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's slightly more complex:

```
preg_match_all('/\[(\d+)\]\n((?:(?!\[).+\n?)+)/', $ini, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

(Could be simplified with knowing the real format constraints.)